# JavaFx - Cancel a MouseEvent

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to get my TitledPane to NOT open when it is in the process of expanding.  I created a boolean variable isExpanding to set to true when it's expanding, and false after it's done expanding.

My issue is that, while using the SceneBuilder GUI, I have a TitledPane that when clicked it expands by default and I don't think I can change that.  What I need is for when my var isExpanding == true then clicking on the TitledPane event is consumed, and it does nothing.

Here is my MouseEvent for when you click on the TitledPane.  After the animation is completed in a different function the isExpanding is set to false.

```
@FXML
private void handleTitledPaneMouseClickDNSAction(MouseEvent event) {
    if( dnsTitledPane.expandedProperty() == null || dnsTitledPane.isExpanded() == false ) {
        animateCollapse( dnsPane, dnsTitledPane );
        isExpanding = false;
    } else {
        expanTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis( 15 ),
            ae -> animateExpanstion( dnsPane, dnsTitledPane )));
        expanTimeline.setCycleCount( Timeline.INDEFINITE );
        expanTimeline.play();
        isExpanding = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just a workaround. You can explicitly `set titledPane Expansion as false` in its mouse click handler.
Here's the code:

```
titlePane.setOnMouseClicked((evt) -> {
  if(isExpanding)
    titlePane.setExpanded(false);
  else
    titlePane.setExpanded(true);
});
```